# Reset mysql user password using hashed password

Tags: mysql

On a mysql server, I made a mistake and changed the wrong user's password, like this:

`SET PASSWORD FOR username@'10.1.%' = PASSWORD('newpassword');`

Before changing the password, I used "SHOW GRANTS FOR username@'10.1.%'" and noted the password hash displayed.  How can I used the hashed password to reset the current password back to the original?  I tried using the same "SET PASSWORD" command with the hash as 'newpassword' but it looks like that literally made the hash the new password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using MySQL 5.6. Here is the process in that version:

**Original password when creating user**

```
create user username@'10.1.%' identified by 'password';
show grants for username@'10.1.%';
```

output:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'10.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19'
```

**Changing password**

```
set password for username@'10.1.%' = PASSWORD('newpassword');
show grants for username@'10.1.%';
```

output:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'10.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*FE4F2D624C07AAEBB979DA5C980D0250C37D8F63'
```

**Reverting password**

```
set password for username@'10.1.%' = '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19';
show grants for username@'10.1.%';
```

output:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'10.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19'
```

Can you check that you are using the entire hashed password? One mistake I've seen is not including the leading asterisk.

Comment: The problem was I was using "password = ('newpassword')" instead of just placing the new password in single quotes after the "=" sign. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [manual of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-password.html) you will see you can use command:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR username@'10.1.%' = 'hashed_password';
```

Comment: I tried this. After using this command, "SHOW GRANTS" command shows a different hashed password from the original.  Why is this so?  I believe this command is making the hashed password the actual password.

Comment: @L.Ray, you can try the things from the end of the link.